# Switch to desktop and back to Modern app in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

For a desktop program of mine, a certain user command requires placing a window on top of the desktop, above everything.
This, unfortunately for me, doesn't behave as intended with Modern apps.

(I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232450/windows-8-layered-windows-over-metro-apps) which apparently solves the problem, but I cannot use this, at least yet)

However, I thought of a workaround - switching to desktop, doing what has to be done, then switching back to the Modern app.
How do I do this in .NET? (preferably C#)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what exactly you're trying to do? Describe the goal, not the step. How would throwing a user to the desktop from a Metro app make sense?

Comment: As I said, it's a user command triggered by a shortcut. More specifically, I take a screenshot, place a window over the whole screen with the image as background and allow users to cut a region out. They need (and expect) to get access to that window.

Comment: I think TopMost in C# might do what you wish.
Set the window to `TopMost=true;` at the initialization and then set it to false again

Comment: That is obviously what I currently use, and it will never display over Modern. There are more requirements that you can find in the link in the question. However, I cannot meet them all. More specifically, for the time being I am unable to: (1) Place the program in a trusted location and (2) Sign the code with a trusted certificate.